# Error in invoking Custom actions in Setup and deployment project in VS2008

Tags: vbscript, setup-deployment

Im using custom actions in my Setup of deployment projects in VS2008. In that im copying some application needed DLL folders in my package. Using custom actions i copied the dlls from 'DLL'folder(available in my products installed Program Files folder) to System 32 or SysWOW64 folder.
while executing the setup.exe, im getting error and installation getting closed.

Here is custom action coding in VBScript

```
dim filesys,filepath,fileexist,sSerialNo,sysfolder
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


MyProperties = Session.Property("CustomActionData")
arrMyProperties = Split(MyProperties, "|")
InstallDir = arrMyProperties(0)
AnotherDir = arrMyProperties(1)    
sSerialNo = InstallDir
MsgBox sSerialNo  //It shows C:\Program Files (x86)\Product
filepath  = sSerialNo & "DLL\"
MsgBox filepath 
fileexist = filepath & "*.dll"
MsgBox fileexist  //It shows C:\Program Files (x86)\Product\DLL\*.dll
sysfolder = AnotherDir
MsgBox sysfolder  //It shows C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
filesys.CopyFile fileexist,sysfolder
```

I have given all msg boxes for checking. It got failed in last line.Before getting this error, when i check Programfiles, all my product related Data got installed and available there.
In Setup project, i gave CustomActionData value as **[TARGETDIR]|[SystemFolder]**

When i use this same script in Installshield Express edition, it works fine.
In Installshield, i used `System.Property()` method to get System directory and Installed directory.

*Error: "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."*

I added three more custom actions.
2.system.vbs -> to create a file in C Drive and write the installation path.
This custom action works fine

3..bat file (firewall setting). I execute this by adding cmd.exe, error occurs when i call this custom action

4. simpe.exe(application to give permission to my application folder) file. Same Error occurs.

In all these customactions, only system.vbs is working.

Comment: 32 bit programs attempting to use `c:\windows\system32` get redirected to `c:\windows\syswow64` which is where 32 bit program's DLLs go. If behaviour is different then the bitness of the program running the script will determine what happens (remembering inbuilt windows programs will start the same bitness as themselves). If a 32 bit program really needs to access the 64 bit `System32` then use this special path for 32 bit programs only `c:\windows\sysnative`.

Comment: @Anu:kindly add the error which you are getting